# core animation xml or json framework

Tags: iphone, xml, ipad, ios4, core-animation

Does anyone know if there is a framework for dynamically loading core animation sequences from some kind of description file like xml or json or even better if there is some kind of core animation studio. I would need some way to allow designers to work on animations without having to talk to programmers for every single change ...

Comment: This is a very good question. You could get them to prototype it in some video editing suite, if there is no XML method.

Comment: good idea about the video editing suit, could be really helpfull in the prototyping phase.

still i find it somehow frustrating, that you have to let a programmer sit down, edit, compile, just to change something simple like a timing or an alpha value ...

Comment: I am working on an animation framework for Cocos2D that allows Flash developers to export animations in Flash and then import them to Cocos2D, but that's probably not what you're looking for?

Comment: @phooze - sounds very interesting, do you develop your library as an opensource project?

Comment: @roman, it's not opensource yet -- it is still too proprietary (hooked up to work for one of our apps).  We are looking into generalizing and releasing it.

Comment: i would be very interested in contributing - contact me if you need help

Comment: roman, cool.  What we have currently is a (rough) Flash --> Cocos2D animation path.  If you can give up Core Animation for Cocos2D...

Comment: There is/was a private API called `CAMLReader` or perhaps `CAMLParser`. It’s unrelated to Caml/OCaml, and it’s what the Weather app uses internally for the animated weather backgrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a project I worked on, we did this exact thing (at least the description part). The animation data is passed down in JSON and parsed and interpreted. It maps to a lot of the major animation capabilities provided by Core Animation--mostly position and frame animations.

Unfortunately what we developed is proprietary and it is highly doubtful the company would be willing to release it as open source.

In the end my answer to your question is there don't appear to be any frameworks that currently support this, however, implementing it yourself wouldn't be too terribly difficult. Then creating a tool your designers can use to generate the animation JSON would be the next logical step. If the tool was not WYSIWYG but rather just a bit of a pseudo design tool, it probably wouldn't be too hard to create either.

Good luck and best regards.

Comment: thank you for your answer, we did more or less the same thing (replace json with xml) in the end. still bugs me that we all seem to be reinventing the wheeel... hope that my company allows me to release the source sooner or later

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for Quartz Composer, except that QC depends heavily on hardware acceleration and isn't available on iOS. Perhaps that will change in the future.